# How To Interpret This Diagram

Tags: sql, database, diagram

I am in a database course this semester and I'm trying to figure out how to interpret this diagram
[image]

I know the key symbols represent either a primary or foreign key, but I can't tell which ones are which.  I think the tables that have the 2 perpendicular lines have at least one foreign key from the table where the line came from, but I am not 100% sure.  That's about all I (think) I understand.

What I really need is someone to either tell me the name of this type of diagram and/or how to interpret it so that I can write the SQL script to represent it.

Comment: Did you try asking the teacher?

Comment: I was going to today in class but class was canceled so I was unable to.  This is actually a diagram from a previous assignment that I already have the solution to, but instead of spending a few hours dissecting it I figured I would just ask on here.

Comment: Im wondering how you got the solution if you didnt understand the logic behind the diagram o^o

Comment: The solution was provided by the professor, he actually gave us the SQL script with the assignment.  I think it was more of a "try it on your own first and if you can't get it use this" kind of assignment.  Basically a way for us to get our feet wet with working with SQL. The only thing I couldn't figure out were the foreign keys.  Mainly the ones in the diagram that had multiple keys.

Comment: Multiple keys in one entity mean a Composite PK. Mean you need all the keys to get an unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A Key symbol mean Primary Key or PK.
- Foreign Key (FK) doesn't have any symbol but you can guess. For example `student.dept_name` is FK from `department.dept_name`
- The arrow go from `department` to `student` mean one department have `0 to N` students
- They are two symbols starting the line one with a circle and another one doble lines. My guess one is `0 .. N` and the other `1 .. N` but without know how you make that diagram can't be sure.
- This diagram is call ER or **[Entity Relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)**
- Each box is a table or Entity you have to create in your script, then create PK, and than define FK.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm seeing in the diagram, although it may not be perfect because not all the keys have their direct lines to their primary sources. The `>O` or `O<` indicates there are required to be many of whatever it's against. An example is there are many students in a department. The `O|` or `|O` indicates there must be 1 and only 1. Each student must be registered with a department, but they can only be registered with one department. The `||` indicates a one to many plurality. Each course can have one or many sections (typically determined by how many students wish to attend that course).

For the issue of the keys, there is no apparent distinction between primary and foreign keys. I would assume that in each case, if a key is simply called ID or includes part of the table name (such as department: dept_name), then it is the primary key and all others are foreign keys. Again, somewhat difficult to tell since not all relationships are mapped in this particular diagram (such as teaches/takes and the key set course_id, semester, & year), but in these cases we assume that it's a composite key (values in multiple fields make up a unique record) rather than a single primary key (although there appears to be a single primary key in the section table). In such cases, simply saying section 01 or 01O doesn't mean anything and will likely return as many rows as there are class titles with a section number equivalent to those. You would have to specify `course_id = CIT261, sec_id = '01O', semester = 'fall', year = 2015` for the first section of an online CIT261 course during the current semester, which should return a single row.

Another interesting note, it would appear that the advisor table satisfies a many to many relationship, and does not contain a primary key, but another composite key, but it doesn't seem to be a solid model as academic advisors are generally tied to the student via the department. This may be meant to reflect the instructors' TA.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

-C§